# How can I set navigator's start&end in Highstock candlestick chart?

Tags: highcharts

I want to set navigator's position and range programmably in Highstock candlestick chart. By default, navigator's end(left) side indicate end of data series. And also width of navigator is seems like fixed some number of data.

In this picture, I want to set navigator to yellow position. How can I do this?

[image: wanted state]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `xAxis` `min` and `max`, to show a specific area on chart load. Can be done like this:

```
xAxis: {
  min: 1330764400000,
  max: 1330774400000
},
```

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/large-dataset.json', function (data) {

    // Create a timer
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    if (!window.TestController) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {
                            text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector: {

            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 3,
                text: '3d'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 1330764400000,
          max: 1330774400000
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Hourly temperatures in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2009-2017'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Built chart in ...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: data.data,
            pointStart: data.pointStart,
            pointInterval: data.pointInterval,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**Working JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/axrce6j3/2/

If you want to show a specific area after the chart has been drawn, you can use the [**`setExtremes`**](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes) function like this:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(1330764400000, 1330774400000, true);
```

API Reference: [Axis.setExtremes()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes)

```js
$.getJSON('https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/057b672172ccc6c08fe7dbb27fc17ebca3f5b770/samples/data/large-dataset.json', function (data) {

    // Create a timer
    var start = +new Date();

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    if (!window.TestController) {
                        this.setTitle(null, {
                            text: 'Built chart in ' + (new Date() - start) + 'ms'
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        rangeSelector: {

            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 3,
                text: '3d'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: '1w'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            selected: 3
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            min: 1330764400000,
          max: 1330774400000
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Hourly temperatures in Vik i Sogn, Norway, 2009-2017'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Built chart in ...' // dummy text to reserve space for dynamic subtitle
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: data.data,
            pointStart: data.pointStart,
            pointInterval: data.pointInterval,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            }
        }]

    });
});

$('#setExtremeButton').click(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts().xAxis[0].setExtremes(1330774400000,1350974400000, true)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
<button id="setExtremeButton">
Set new min/max
</button>
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/axrce6j3/12/

Comment: It works that way I wanted, thanks. I wonder it also possible to set xAxis min max and redraw the chart after first load?

Comment: Great! It is possible, see my updated answer for how you can do this.

Comment: Thanks, you are a master!